# Why should I define an order for categories using OrdinalEncoder?

Tags: python, analytics, decision-tree

I have a dataset with more than 2 possible values in some columns(like low, medium, high, very high).
The OrdinalEncoder allows me with the command
`OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['low','medium','high', very high]])` 
a definition of a an order of this values.

In this example the OrdinalEncoder would transform:
| string    | float    |
| --------- | -------- |
| low       | 0        |
| medium    | 1        |
| high      | 2        |
| very high | 3        |

By default, OrdinalEncoder would take the alphabetical order that will lead to:
| string    | float    |
| --------- | -------- |
| high      | 0        |
| low       | 1        |
| medium    | 2        |
| very high | 3        |

But both cases lead to same solutions regarding:

- optimal depth of the decision tree
- accuracy
- recall
- precision

Is this option only for better understanding of the output or does it affect the output in some cases?
In what cases does it matter to define a order for catergories?